# Function: smallest positive integer

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int enough(int goal)
{
    
    int C { };
    int i { };
    if (goal > 1)
    {
        while (((C += i) <= goal) && ((goal - i) <= (i + 1)))
        {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    cout << enough(21);
    return 0;
}
```

So the purpose of this function is for it to return the smallest positive integer that can be summed consecutively from 1 before the cumulative sum becomes greater than the parameter "goal".

So, for example:

```
cout << enough(9) << endl;
```

will print 4 because 1+2+3+4 > 9 but 1+2+3<9

```
cout << enough(21) << endl;
```

will print 6 'cause 1+2+ . . .+6 > 21 but 1+2+ . . . 5<21

```
cout << enough(-7) << endl;
```

will print 1 because 1 > -7 and 1 is the smallest positive integer

```
cout << enough(1) << endl;
```

will print 1 because 1 = 1 and 1 is the smallest positive integer

My logic at first was using just `while ((C += i) <= goal)`, but that went wrong, for example, for the parameter 21, where you get `C` = 20, which passes the test and ends up in `i` being augmented by 1 (resulting in the return value `i` = 7, which is clearly wrong).

Therefore I decided to create a test which tested both `C` and `i`, but that went wrong because the code isn't considering `goal - i` and `i + 1` as separate tests for the while circuit, but I believe it is actually altering the value of `int`s `goal` and `i`, which screws everything up.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: Edit: turns out the solution to this problem is through finding the highest divisor, but it should be possible to solve the way I attempted, I just need to find a way to isolate the tests making so that the while doesn't alter the parameters value.

Comment: @dxiv: Indeed - I've written it out waiting for a calculation to complete (which itself can probably be sped up: do what I say not what I do ;-) )

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is unnecessarily verbose. There is a closed-form (i.e. O(1)) solution for this.

The sum S of the arithmetic progression 1, 2, ..., n is

```
S = n * (n + 1) / 2
```

Rearranging this (completing the square), rejecting the spurious root, and rounding appropriately to fit the requirements of the question yields the result

```
n = std::ceil((-1 + std::sqrt(1 + 8 * S)) / 2)
```

This will not work for negative `n`, and possibly 0 too depending on the specific (and unspecified) requirements.

---

Or if you *must* use an O(N) approach, then

```
int enough(int goal){
    int i = 0;
    for (int total = 0; (total += ++i, total) < goal; );
    return i;
}
```

will do it, which returns 1 for `goal <= 1`.

Comment: Do you really advertise something like `(total += ++i, total) < goal`? I hope this is just to prevent a beginner from just using the solution as an answer in a test / homework.

Comment: Out of the exact sciences for 3 years, forgot that converting a sum to an expression even existed. That's a great idea, damn.

Answer (score 3):

You could perhaps try to simplify your original `O(N)` approach by only having one condition in your `while-loop`, i.e., no `&&`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int enough(int goal)
{
    if (goal <= 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int total{};
    int i{};
    while (total < goal)
    {
        total += ++i;
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "enough(9): " << enough(9) << endl;
    cout << "enough(21): " << enough(21) << endl;
    cout << "enough(-7): " << enough(-7) << endl;
    cout << "enough(1): " << enough(1) << endl;
    cout << "enough(0): " << enough(0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
enough(9): 4
enough(21): 6
enough(-7): 1
enough(1): 1
enough(0): 1
```

Comment: `total += ++i;` +1 for evil genius.